# Cannot read property 'have' of undefined when testing Material-UI Component with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme, storybook

I am working on [Storybook] tutorial, but using `Material-UI` as a UI-Framework.
I have completed to the point where I have the `Task` and `TaskList` components available.
I started working with writing test using `Jest` and `enzyme`, and this is where things started to shake up.

My test looks like

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TaskList from "./TaskList";
import { withPinnedTasks } from "../../stories/TaskList.stories";
import { MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { theme } from "../theme";
import { createMount } from "@material-ui/core/test-utils";

describe("SearchField", () => {
  let mount;
  beforeEach(() => {
    mount = createMount();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mount.cleanUp();
  });

  it("renders pinned tasks at the start of the list", () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const events = { onPinTask: jest.fn(), onArchiveTask: jest.fn() };

    let wrapper = mount(
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <TaskList tasks={withPinnedTasks} {...events} />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );

    console.log(wrapper);

    // We expect the task titled "Task 6 (pinned)" to be rendered first, not at the end
    const lastTaskInput = wrapper.find('#id').to.have.lengthOf(1);

    // querySelector(
    //   '.list-item:nth-child(1) input[value="Task 6 (pinned)"]'
    // );
    expect(lastTaskInput).not.toBe(null);

    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });
});
```

and when I run `yarn test`, it fails with the following error

```
  ● SearchField › renders pinned tasks at the start of the list

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

      30 |
      31 |     // We expect the task titled "Task 6 (pinned)" to be rendered first, not at the end
    > 32 |     const lastTaskInput = wrapper.find('#id').to.have.lengthOf(1);
         |                           ^
      33 |
      34 |     // querySelector(
      35 |     //   '.list-item:nth-child(1) input[value="Task 6 (pinned)"]'

      at Object.it (src/components/TaskList.test.js:32:27)
```

The entire codebase is available at https://codesandbox.io/s/github/hhimanshu/storyboook-materialui-react/tree/jest

But since this is a failure in the test, if you are looking for the direct github link, you can find this at  https://github.com/hhimanshu/storyboook-materialui-react/tree/jest

I am seeking help with following things
1. What all is incorrect in this code? I am learning to test using `Jest` and `enzyme` and would love to know what I need to learn
2. How can I test `Material-UI` custom themed components using `MuiThemeProvider`.

Thank you

Comment: Aren't you forgetting an `expect`? It this what you what you want to test `expect(wrapper.find('#id')).to.have.lengthOf(1);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `.to.have` is proper jest syntax, I believe the enzyme docs assume a different testing framework? Check here for what can be called on a jest `expect` method call

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect

Looks like you'll need something like

`const lastTaskInput = expect(wrapper.find('#id').length).toEqual(1);`

Read from here specifically...

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#toequalvalue